# Google Data Studio, how to count or count distinct the text data

Tags: looker-studio

[image]

So I made a table with several data source including the one from google analytics.
Now the issue is that, the blue circle one which is a code of customers like aaa1, bbb2, when I do count or count distinct the result is always very smaller(like 1 or 0 even though the actual number is more than 10) than the actual.
I think this is because of All Web Site Data...

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift the data source to the left,

```
The leftmost data source provides the master set of records to include in the blend, while the records in data sources to the right are included only if they match the join keys.
```

See the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061421?hl=en)

Comment: I see. So which one is the most left is relating ya. umm ok. Sounds like it's hard to do count in here.

Comment: It's not hard, you just need to understand the logic of how Data Studio is handling the blended data sources.